# Lenovo G580 with trackpad issues on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Tags: touchpad

My laptop is a Lenovo G580 and I recently upgraded to 13.10.
When I wake it up from sleep the track-pad stops working and a little banner in the conner of the screen has a picture of a track-pad with an x over it.

Please help, I really don't want to have to re-install from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar problem with my lenovo thinkpad t400
after trying any other method I am remember that now ubuntu have many GUI based setting (after alot of hassle to install usb modem)
just do this :

1. click ubuntu setting icon (icon that looks like gear on the top right of ubuntu panel
2. click system setting
3. click/choose mouse touchpad under hardware
4. check if touchpad is disabled if disabled swift to on